# Grouping and summing a multi-dimension array

Tags: php

Hi I have the following mult-dimensional array:

[image: Multi-dimensional array]

I would like to group by the CustID and sum zero_days, thirty_60 ..etc

I can sum the totals as follows:

```
$zero_30 = array_sum(array_column($aging,'zero_30'));
$thirty_60 = array_sum(array_column($aging,'thirty_60'));
$sixty_90 = $array_sum(array_column($aging,'sixty_90'));
$ninety_plus = array_sum(array_column($aging,'ninety_plus'));
```

However I am not sure how I could produce an array where totals are summed by each CustID ?

Comment: Iterate over array and sum, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```php
$result = [];
foreach ($array as $data) {

    $custID = $data->CustID;

    // If you don't have the current CustID : you create it and add all data
    if (!isset($result[$custID])) {
        $result[$custID] = $data;
    } 
    // Now if you have one entry : you just sum the data with the one you already have
    else {
         $result[$custID]->zero_days   += $data->zero_days;
         $result[$custID]->thirty_60   += $data->thirty_60;
         $result[$custID]->sixty_90    += $data->sixty_90;
         $result[$custID]->ninety_plus += $data->ninety_plus;
    }
}
```